# picamera: Incorrect buffer length error when resizing in picamera.capture

Tags: python, python-3, picamera

I am trying to use picamera to record and save a high resolution video, and capture low resolution images for processing using openCV.

```py
import picamera
import picamera.array
import cv2
import numpy as np

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1920, 1088)
camera.framerate = 30

camera.start_recording('testRecording.h264')

cap=picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera, size = (640,368))

for x in range(250):
        
    print(x)
    cap=picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera)
    camera.capture(cap, use_video_port=True, resize = (640,368), format="bgr")
    img=cap.array 
    cv2.imshow("resized image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I have tried using this code, and it throws the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/recordingTest/simultanious capture test.py", line 18, in <module>
    camera.capture(cap, use_video_port=True, resize = (640,360), format="bgr")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1421, in capture
    if not encoder.wait(self.CAPTURE_TIMEOUT):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 395, in wait
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 419, in stop
    self._close_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 349, in _close_output
    mo.close_stream(output, opened)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 371, in close_stream
    stream.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 238, in flush
    self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 127, in bytes_to_rgb
    'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height))
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 1920x1088
```

By removing `resize = (640,368)` from line 18, the code no longer errors, however, the capture is then taken at the full resolution, and I want a low resolution image.

I know I could resize the capture afterwards, but I believe this would be more intensive on the Pi, so would ideally like to just capture a low res image in the first place.

Any help understanding the cause of this, and finding a solution that works would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you would like to store an image in a buffer, you need to:

1. **Initialize** the buffer (`cap` variable in your code) with the size of image you want to store (640, 368 in your case)
2. **Put image** to the buffer (using `camera.capture(cap, ...)`)
3. **Clear the buffer** before you will use it again (`cap.truncate(0)`) - it is easy to forget about it, and the error says that the buffer length is incorrect, which can be confusing

The problem in your code is that the `cap` variable is assigned twice (before and inside loop) and it is not truncated after each iteration.

The corrected code below should work fine:

```
import picamera
import picamera.array
import cv2
import numpy as np

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1920, 1088)
camera.framerate = 30

camera.start_recording('testRecording.h264')

cap=picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera, size = (640,368))

for x in range(250):
    print(x)
    camera.capture(cap, use_video_port=True, resize = (640,368), format="bgr")
    img=cap.array 
    cv2.imshow("resized image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cap.truncate(0)
```

Changes:

1. `cap=picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera)` line was removed
2. `cap.truncate(0)` was added